# HTML form input javascript autosum total price to pay

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I have the follow code to sell a product, if I apply discount it works, same if I apply taxes, all prices per unit (quantity 1) is working, but the total price to pay if I change quantity is not working

What I need is to autofill to later save to mysql the follow fields:

```
default price per unit (comming from mysql) = working
apply taxes or not per unit = working
apply discount per unit = working
price per unit after discount and after taxes = working
```

total price to pay if I change quantity from 1 to 2 o 3 etc = not working
this must be autofilled by multiplicate price to pay after taxes per unit by quantity = not working

here is the code

```
<table width="339" border="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="98">Pay taxes?</td>
    <td width="115">Make Discount?</td>
    <td width="118">Default unit price</td>
     <td>Quantity</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <select name="taxes" class="select">
        <option value="0" selected>no taxes</option>
        <option value="19">19% taxes</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <select name="discount" class="select">
        <option value="0" selected>no discount</option>
        <option value="5">5% discount</option>
        <option value="10">10% discount</option>
        <option value="20">20% discount</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="cost" class="input140" value="1000">
    </td>
    <td><input type="text" name="quantity" value="1"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Unit price after discount</td>
    <td>Tax per unit</td>
    <td>Total Price per unit</td>
     <td>Total Price to pay per quantity</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="price" value="1000"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="ttaxes" value="0"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="total" value="1000"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="totaltopay" value="1000"></td>
  </tr>
 </table><script>
/**
 * Elements
 */
var taxes    = document.getElementsByName('taxes')[0];
var discount = document.getElementsByName('discount')[0];
var cost     = document.getElementsByName('cost')[0];
var price    = document.getElementsByName('price')[0];
var ttaxes   = document.getElementsByName('ttaxes')[0];
var total    = document.getElementsByName('total')[0];


/**
 * Calculations
 */
function updateInput() {
  price.value = cost.value - (cost.value * (discount.value / 100));
  ttaxes.value = (price.value * (taxes.value / 100));
  var sum = parseFloat(price.value) + parseFloat(ttaxes.value);
  total.value = sum.toFixed(0);
}


/**
 * Event Listeners
 */
taxes.addEventListener('change', updateInput);
discount.addEventListener('change', updateInput);
cost.addEventListener('change', updateInput);
cost.addEventListener('keyup', updateInput);
</script>
```

Here is the demo Fiddle

https://fiddle.jshell.net/63dkvgs5/

image example of what I need

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add **quantity**!

```
var quantity = document.getElementsByName('quantity')[0];
quantity.addEventListener('keyup', updateInput);
```

And update the calculation:

```
var sum = (parseFloat(price.value) + parseFloat(ttaxes.value)) * quantity.value;
```

**Fiddle: https://fiddle.jshell.net/praveenscience/v6spxoqv/**

Comment: Almost perfect, the price per unit after discount and taxes must not be modify but the total price to pay the last field must sum total price per uni * quantity

Comment: Your code is updating the the total price per unit but not the total price to pay the last field

Comment: Can you please help me do this? The code must sum in the last field total price to pay per quantity the sum of total price per unit after discount after tax * quantity

Comment: Wait. You are confusing. What should happen if I put `5` in the quantity?

Comment: If I put 5 in quantity then it updates the last field (Total Price to pay per quantity) by multiplicate total field by quantity field

Comment: What **should** happen?

Comment: Updated my answer and added a image with what I need it to do

Answer (score 0):

```
<table width="339" border="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="98">Pay taxes?</td>
    <td width="115">Make Discount?</td>
    <td width="118">Default unit price</td>
     <td>Quantity</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
   <select name="taxes" class="select">
    <option value="0" selected>no taxes</option>
    <option value="5">5% taxes</option>
    <option value="10">10% taxes</option>
    <option value="20">20% taxes</option>
    <option value="27">27% taxes</option>
    <option value="30">30% taxes</option>
    <option value="40">40% taxes</option>
    <option value="50">50% taxes</option>
   </select>
    </td>
    <td>
   <select name="discount" class="select">
    <option value="0" selected>no discount</option>
    <option value="5">5% discount</option>
    <option value="10">10% discount</option>
    <option value="20">20% discount</option>
   </select>
    </td>
    <td>
     <input type="text" name="cost" class="input140" value="100">
    </td>
    <td><input type="text" name="quantity" value="1"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Unit price after discount</td>
    <td>Tax per unit</td>
    <td>Total Price per unit</td>
     <td>Végösszeg Total Price to pay per quantity</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="price" value="100"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="ttaxes" value="0"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="total" value="100"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="totaltopay" value="100"></td>
  </tr>
 </table>
<script>
/* Elements */
var taxes    = document.getElementsByName('taxes')[0];
var discount = document.getElementsByName('discount')[0];
var cost     = document.getElementsByName('cost')[0];
var price    = document.getElementsByName('price')[0];
var ttaxes   = document.getElementsByName('ttaxes')[0];
var total    = document.getElementsByName('total')[0];
var totaltopay = document.getElementsByName('totaltopay')[0];
var quantity = document.getElementsByName('quantity')[0];
quantity.addEventListener('keyup', updateInput);
/* Calculations */
function updateInput() {
  price.value = cost.value - (cost.value * (discount.value / 100));
  ttaxes.value = (price.value * (taxes.value / 100));
  totaltopay.value = (price.value * quantity.value) + (taxes.value * quantity.value);
  var sum = parseFloat(price.value) + parseFloat(ttaxes.value);
  total.value = sum.toFixed(0);
  var sum = (parseFloat(price.value) + parseFloat(ttaxes.value)) * quantity.value;
}
/* Event Listeners */
taxes.addEventListener('change', updateInput);
discount.addEventListener('change', updateInput);
cost.addEventListener('change', updateInput);
cost.addEventListener('keyup', updateInput);
</script>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer ,Posting only code snippet doesn't help other user